# How to say "same as" in one word?

Tags: single-word-requests

Yesterday the "[DAMN.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damn_(album))" album came out and people have been asking me about my thoughts on it. Because I want to sound high-brow I'd like to say that my reaction is same as the album's name? `My reaction ... to the album's name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a word "echo"that may express your idea.
Echo: [VN] to repeat an idea or opinion because you agree with it. (From Oxford Dictionary )
So you may put it like this: 
My reaction echoes the album's name.

Answer (score 1):

[Ditto](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ditto%20Ditto)

1
:  a thing mentioned previously or above —used to avoid repeating a word —often symbolized by inverted commas or apostrophes
2
:  a ditto mark